# How do I use prepared statements in Athena with boto3?

Tags: prepared-statement, boto3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to use the prepared statements added in athena engine version 2 using boto3. I see api docs for CreatePreparedStatement but nothing for executing the prepared statement
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePreparedStatement.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2):

The [boto3 Athena documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client) does not specify an API to execute a prepared statement directly currently. A possible workaround would be to get the PreparedStatement object by calling [get_prepared_statement()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_prepared_statement), extracting the query statement from the object, and run [start_query_execution()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution) with it.

Answer (score 1):

You just submit a SQL statement with `Client.start_query_execution`

```
Execute prepared_statement_name 'param1','param2', etc...
```

Comment: I think this could use a little more explanation. There's no mention of this method being related to prepared statements [in the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena/client/start_query_execution.html).